# How to handle custom back navigation in an android activity

Tags: android

What is the best practice to handle back navigation in an android activity?

Currently I'm building a stack (Stack class) of my own which holds anonymous functions which will be executed onBackPressed().

Please don't be scared of the scala code:

```
val actionStack: mutable.Stack[() => Any] = mutable.Stack(
  () => { moveTaskToBack(true); finish() }
)

override def onBackPressed() {
     actionStack.pop.apply()
}

def doSth() = {
    actionStack.push(() => contentView.removeView(composeView))
}
```

This is working fine, but I was wondering if there is a built in way to achieve this?

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: unfortunately not. Still using that code.

Comment: I hope this help you , see my answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700106/2758345

Answer (score 0):

[There](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) is official guide for providing proper navigation in various cases (Activities,fragments, web views)

Comment: right, but here (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) it doesn't say how to handle e.g. adding a compose overlay and removing it onBackPressed.